# Issues with Kimono Api, Unexpected Tokon O

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

So im trying to make a jquery request to kimono to get information from the api. I'm getting "unexpected token o" when i inspect element in the console in chrome.

Basically im way out of my depth here, I'm trying to get the text field pulled into a table The closest i got was pulling the whole json into the webpage.

Sam

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true'); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Link</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ca266cam?apikey=zdRSeNfI0Nnr8GJ9KgSbc6awtvvSyOYh',
        success: function (data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
             for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
              var title = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.text;
              var href = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.href;
              $("table").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+href+"</td></tr>");

            }
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Thats my main php file! The Url link if clicked will show the json. Any ideas would be great. Pleas say its something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your ajax call like below,it worked for me.The problem seems to be related to `$.parseJSON(data)` line.The response you are receiving from server is already a javaScript Object,So no need to parse that.

```
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/ca266cam?apikey=zdRSeNfI0Nnr8GJ9KgSbc6awtvvSyOYh',
          success: function (json) {
               //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
               for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
                 var title = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.text;
                 var href = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.href;
                 $("table").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+href+"</td></tr>");
               }
         },
         error: function(error){
              console.log(error);
         }
       });
```

Comment: Brilliant that works!, Quick question, if i wanted to add a table class for results how would one do that?